# Invert a frequency table

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Given a frequency table that is the result of many manipulations (there is *no* range like A1:B5 - if it were then this is straight forward)

Is there a way to invert using formulas like

source:

```
[
  [ 1, 3],
  [ 2, 0],
  [ 5, 4]
]
```

result (as a string):

```
"1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5"
```

I would like to avoid using macros.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the questions, then resolved it.

Solution is to process before the 2d array is created.

=TEXTJOIN( ",", TRUE, MID( REPT( "," & *first_column*, _second_column ), 2, 1000 ) )